# this code is not working on device but on simultor ?? any idea i have 3Gs i think

Tags: iphone

i want to embed compass on my application can any one help me plz

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    //Start the compass updates.
    //[self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
    [[self locationManager] startUpdatingHeading];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    NSLog(@"New magnetic heading: %f", newHeading.magneticHeading);
    NSLog(@"New true heading: %f", newHeading.trueHeading);
}
```

this code is not working on device its only running on simulator??? any idea ???

Comment: Does your device have the compass feature?!

Comment: how to know that?? plz tell i am havig 3gs  i have defualt Angle app on my iphone and its working soo  i think i have :(

Comment: i think i have 3G not 3Gs :( so can i run??  i am saying 3G because i dont have video recording option so i guess its 3G now can i run this on my iphone??

Answer (score 0):

Use [Core Location](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/index.html)

A search on the docs for *compass* is not that hard...

Comment: but do i need to use maps for that or just coreloc will do??